# Spring Jars difference

Tags: spring, jar

I Have the basic question regarding the jars-"spring-beans.jar" from Spring 4_1.5 release to "org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.jar" What is the difference between the two jars and their usage perspectives in the projects

Comment: Just read a change log and upgrade guide to get the answer http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html

Comment: @yorlin,@cool  Please try to understand what I am asking, see what is the difference between the jars "spring-beans" and "org.springframework.beans" no matter what is the version of the both!!! Why two different jars??

Comment: Then you should try to ask the question more precisely, f.e. Why the jars has different names, but not the difference between jars, while the difference is exactly that they have a different versions. Actually there is no matter what is the name of jar, you can rename it and it will work. It's just a decision of developers, based on some internal reconstruction. There is no difference how to use both of this jars, except the version specific code implementation. To make both of them to work just place it in project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the differences are but I am sure lots of differences.
the suffix X.Y.Z indicates the version of jar. "X" is the major and Y is the minor version. "Z" generally contains bug fixes and performance improvements etc.
"Y" contains small new features. "X" contains dramatic changes like new Java version support new techology supports etc.